# IntlDateFormatter parsing my date incorrectly

Tags: php, cakephp

Trying to get `CakePHP` 3.4 to parse my dates correctly using their [locale parser](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#parsing-localized-datetime-data).

I had it set up as described and it was consistently parsing my date incorrectly. I've located the apparent problem section being the [datefmt_create](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php) function from the `php-intl` extension.

The relevant line in `CakePHP` is [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.5/src/I18n/DateFormatTrait.php#L321) if you are interested.

```
$formatter = datefmt_create(
    'en_US',
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'UTC',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
);

$time = $formatter->parse('02/02/2011 12:34');

echo date('r', $time);
```

Why does the above code return `Sun, 19 Dec 2010 12:34:00 +0000`?

I am expecting to see `Wed, 02 Feb 2011 12:34:00 +0000`.

**Disclaimer**: I am aware of alternate methods of date parsing, I am solely interest in why *this* method is not behaving as I am expecting it to.

Comment: i think your code also work if you change YYYY to yyyy. have a look at https://3v4l.org/4ISuW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Since you are using PHP function `datefmt_create` this is not a CakePHP problem at all.

Second: You are mixing up procedural style (`datefmt_create`) and object oriented style (`$formatter->parse`) – you should decide which way you want to go.

**The problem you came for:**
You are using the wrong syntax inside the `datefmt_create` function. Check the syntac [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

This code will do what you expect:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$formatter = datefmt_create(
    'en_US',
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'UTC',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'
);

// I used `datefmt_parse` instead since it’s also the procedural way to go
$time = datefmt_parse($formatter, '02/02/2011 12:34');

echo date('r', $time);
```

**Output:**

```
Wed, 02 Feb 2011 12:34:00 +0000
```

Comment: 1st: I know it is not a `CakePHP` problem, I specified clearly it was an `IntlDateFormatter` problem. 2nd: I used it the way `CakePHP` used it to replicate the issue as identically as possible, (regardless I don't see any problem using it this way). 3rd: You are correct, I used the wrong year syntax, thanks.

Comment: Well, then why even mention CakePHP? ;-) *"Trying to get CakePHP 3.4 to parse my dates correctly using their locale parser."* – Nevermind, you’re welcome. Glad it worked.

Comment: Okay, I got you now. You thought that maybe the core code of CakePHP could be the problem. Didn’t get that right. ;-)

Comment: the code of question also work if you change YYYY to yyyy. have a look at https://3v4l.org/4ISuW

Comment: That’s what I’m saying @ChetanAmeta. It’s just that mixing up OOP and procedural style where it is unnecessary, feels wrong. I’d prefer OOP, but be consequent then and use `new IntlDateFormatter(...)` instead.